# Visual Studio show an error about PrismApplication

Tags: xamarin, prism

Now and then I get XamlC error XFC0000 : Cannot resolve type "PrismApplication" in the error list of my shared xamarin project. The error is from App.xaml and no squiggly is shown in that file, but the error is shown in the error list. Sometimes it goes away if a restart visual studio. I'm running Prism.Unity.Forms v7.2.0.1422.
I shoud mention that my android project still builds when the error is shown, but it's annoying and I like to know how to remove it?
Maybe it can be done like something like suppressing the error about Ambiguity between 'Resource.Layout.Tabbar' and 'Resource.Layout.Tabbar.

Comment: I am seeing the same issue with PrismApplication and PopupPage.  Have you found a solution other than ignoring the errors?  The app still builds and works fine.

Comment: Does your App.xaml define xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com" ?

Comment: @DevenCC Mine does, and this is a real pain, because it seems to stop hot reloading from working :(

Comment: @MarkErickson See my answer below, I also had the error with both PrismApplication and PopupPage.

Answer (score 4):

I am using Prism with DryIoc (and not unity). Following a suggestion from another thread I replaced

`xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com"`

with

`xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.DryIoc;assembly=Prism.DryIoc.Forms"`

in my App.xaml file and the error disappeared.

I had the same error with PopupPage from Rg.Plugins.Popup, so I also replaced

`xmlns:pages="http://rotorgames.com"`

with

`xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"`

and that error disappeared as well.

As these are two different libraries, acting similarly, it might be a general VS issue. But could also be the same error in two libraries.

Another thread lead me to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/custom-namespace-schemas#consuming-a-custom-namespace-schema) which basically says that using a custom namespace requires a direct reference to the assembly through C# code in order for VS to find it and not show this error.

Answer (score 0):

You could ignore it. Click the Code of the Error List window and clear filter the error which you do not want to show.

[image]

Uncheck the error you want to ignore.

[image]

Comment: Thanks I knew about this. But it doesn't really solve it, the error code is only shown in description and not in the Code column - sure I can select hidiing Blank but that might hide something else important.
But the biggest problem is that it still shows an Error above the column-headers it says: 0 of 1 error - and our manager want it to say 0 Errors.

Comment: Based on my search, i do not find the way to say 0 error. You could check the suggestions in the link below. It would be helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24309096/visual-studio-extension-how-to-intercept-modify-delete-build-error-messages

Answer (score 0):

My issue was solved as I set my Android project as "Set as Startup Project"

[image]